# Create trigger on update and insert into customized table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a requirement where i have to  create a trigger when there is an update in "psoprdefn" table for specific roles from "psroleuser"  and insert values into my customized table.

For some reason the below trigger does'nt seem to work. Please help.

```
CREATE TRIGGER z_LOGIN2
AFTER UPDATE OF lastsignondttm  ON SYSADM.PSOPRDEFN
FOR EACH ROW     
BEGIN
SELECT DISTINCT a.oprid, a.oprdefndesc, a.lastsignondttm, b.rolename
from SYSADM.psoprdefn a, SYSADM.psroleuser b
where a.oprid=b.roleuser
and (rolename = 'FAS Change Admin' or b.rolename='PeopleSoft Administrator')
INSERT INTO z_LOGIN       VALUES(psoprdefn.oprid,psoprdefn.oprdefndesc,psoprdefn.lastlogondttm)
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific on what are you trying to do? Your trigger looks a little weird to start. Do you want to insert the new updated values in z_Login? Or you want to insert always the results of that select?

Comment: Okay, i am trying to create a trigger wherein when the user login to the system,his details are automatically updated in psoprdefn table. And whenever he logs in to the table and if he has 'FAS Change Admin' or 'PeopleSoft Administrator' as role i am trying to select those details and inserting into my custom table z_login.

Comment: yes i always want to insert values to that my z_login table

Comment: And you want to validate on psroleuser if he has rolename 'FAS Change Admin' or  'PeopleSoft Administrator'. If he does, you want to insert the new values that were updated in psoprdefn or the old ones before the update?

Comment: I Want the new values (oprid,oprdefndesc,lastsignondttm ) that are updated in the table psoprdefn for that user into my z table ) . For example user David logged in today

Comment: I Want the new values (oprid,oprdefndesc,lastsignondttm ) that are updated in the table psoprdefn for that user into my z table ) . For example user David logged in today so the lastsignondttm  in the psoprdefn table would be 11/25/2013 5:17:01.182884 PM and i want these details to be inserted into my Ztable. YES i want new vales to be inserted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER z_LOGIN2 AFTER UPDATE OF lastsignondttm ON SYSADM.PSOPRDEFN
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
  IF (SELECT COUNT(1)
      FROM SYSADM.psroleuser b
      WHERE b.roleuser = NEW.oprid AND (b.rolename = 'FAS Change Admin'
            OR b.rolename = 'PeopleSoft Administrator')) > 0 THEN

  INSERT INTO z_LOGIN VALUES (NEW.oprid,NEW.oprdefndesc,NEW.lastlogondttm);
 END IF;

END;
```

This validates if the user that updated the original table has a rolename of 'FAS Change Admin' or 'PeopleSoft Administrator' in psroleuser. If he does, it inserts the updated values in the z_LOGIN table.

Comment: This worked fine, However i have to insert few more fields to z_login table. Z_Login table has 7 fields .
database_option = this shd say which sys  we are in like tst, dev or prd, so is there any system variable for this?
reasondesc= this is the user i/p
last_oprid = user
update_dttm = sysdate
INSERT INTO z_LOGIN VALUES (NEW.oprid,NEW.oprdefndesc,NEW.lastlogondttm ,sydb? ,'reson',user,sysdate).

Comment: Hi Silva, Not sure how will i get the database name

Comment: To get the selected DB you can do `SELECT DATABASE() FROM DUAL`. To get the current user you can do `SELECT USER()`. To get the sysdate you can do: NOW(). The last oprid is OLD.oprid. Try adding those to the insert and see if it does what you want

Comment: Except for database i am getting values in other fields
INSERT INTO SYSADM.PS_FZAP_AUDITLOGIN VALUES (psoprdefn.oprid,psoprdefn.oprdefndesc,psoprdefn.lastsignondttm,database,'test',user,sysdate);

Comment: The fieldname for database is dbname (character 8)

Comment: Here's what i was telling you to try: `INSERT INTO z_LOGIN VALUES (NEW.oprid,NEW.oprdefndesc,NEW.lastlogondttm ,SELECT DATABASE() FROM DUAL,OLD.oprid,SELECT USER(),NOW())` . Try simply `SELECT DATABASE() FROM DUAL` to see if it returns what you want. [example here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/26308)

Comment: Hi Silva,
I get an error for the above statement for 'SELECT DATABASE() FROM DUAL' , i am working on peoplesoft and i checked dual table/record does not exist

Comment: Aren't you using mysql? I don't know any other way of doing that.

Comment: I am using Toad , this one worked fine SELECT NAME FROM v$database and thanks for all ur help. The trigger code worked perfectly fine

Comment: yes to fetch the database name SELECT NAME FROM v$database works, sorry i  did not mention earlier tat it is toad so i cudnt get SELECT DATABASE() FROM DUAL working

Comment: Awesome! Just checking that you got it to work. :). If you feel this answer helped, consider marking it as accepted (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) on how to do that)